# How can I make TeamCity pull all tags when it checks out the source code?

Tags: git, tags, teamcity, gitversion

I use `GitVersion` in my builds and I'm getting different results on TeamCity than locally, I think because TeamCity isn't pulling tags from the repository, so GitVersion never gets to see them and computes the wrong semantic version.

How can I ensure that TeamCity pulls all tags when checking out the source?

Note: I've set my branch specification to:

```
+:refs/heads/(*)
+:refs/tags/(*)
```

But that hasn't helped and I don't think it is really what I need. I don't particularly want to *build* tags (I build every commit regardless of whether it is tagged) - I just need them to be available for GitVersion.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make TeamCity pull down all git branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23733970/make-teamcity-pull-down-all-git-branches)

Answer (score 0):

It should be for Branch specification

```
+:refs/tags/*
```

As well as having **Use tags as branches**